Unable to apply helmert 2D transformation on postgis
Below is the proj4 string that i'm currently using to perform Helmert 2D transformation on a Northing, Easting coordinate
+proj=helmert +s=0.9999604139 +theta=631.04845752  +x=-964.588163325253  +y=509.453993969838 +exact +convention=coordinate_frame
St_transform of a point is returning null for the above proj4 string.
I want to know whether

Helmert projections are supported in postgis?
Please point me to examples of how to use helmert 2D transforms in proj4

PostGIS Version() - "3.3 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"

The theta value should be smaller. I don't know if it's supposed to be specified in degrees (thus between -360 and +360) or in radians. You can also omit +convention which only applies in a 3D Helmert transformation. I don't have any further information.

Theta value i used here is in arc seconds….however helmert 2D similarity transformation I’m finding it difficult to apply

arc-seconds are used for the 3D Helmert, not the 2D Helmert. In degrees, 0.1752912382
